# Polynomial regression predicts a straight line

Tags: python, data-analysis

I want to make a polynomial regression (third degree), but I just get straight lines if I go under 4th degree.
I have no experience in data analysis and basically just copied the code from somewhere and fed it my data.
My y data is standardized and the x values are simply the years from 1950-2018.

The problems start with the x value, if I use the years it does not work at all, it will simply predict a straight line no matter which degree I choose. But if I use a the index to fit the model it at least works for degree 4 and higher

But I only want to test degree 2 and 3 degree.

My code:

```
x = np.array(list(range(1, 70)))
y = np.array([-1.07312323, -1.12360264, -1.16848888, -1.21237286, -1.24931163,
   -1.24563078, -1.25029589, -1.25804974, -1.26992981, -1.2759396 ,
   -1.31707672, -1.28845207, -1.2553561 , -1.21670196, -1.17405228,
   -1.13823657, -1.10201293, -1.0652651 , -1.01830663, -0.95872599,
   -0.86864519, -0.77287454, -0.67380868, -0.56936508, -0.47234488,
   -0.38025164, -0.28073984, -0.17953134, -0.08026437,  0.01376177,
    0.09177617,  0.15270399,  0.2005737 ,  0.23841612,  0.2860362 ,
    0.34606907,  0.39385415,  0.44154466,  0.49050035,  0.5338063 ,
    0.58003198,  0.61416929,  0.59416923,  0.56887929,  0.53366038,
    0.4907952 ,  0.45338928,  0.40975728,  0.35098762,  0.29307093,
    0.24168722,  0.21576624,  0.25267974,  0.3066606 ,  0.37672389,
    0.45321951,  0.53410345,  0.62491894,  0.72720349,  0.81841313,
    0.9213128 ,  1.03645707,  1.15479503,  1.25998302,  1.35221566,
    1.44653627,  1.52833712,  1.60458778,  1.68225894])

# transforming the data to include another axis
x = x[:, np.newaxis]
y = y[:, np.newaxis]

polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
x_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y)
y_poly_pred = model.predict(x_poly)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=10)
plt.plot(x, y_poly_pred, color='m')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot for the code with degree 4:

[image: 4th degree]

This is what it looks like if I go with degree 3 or less:

[image: 3rd degree]

Is my data in the wrong format or is the code not working? I tried several other code snippets and had similar problems.
Or do I have simply no clue on polynomial regression and missing something important?

BTW I do not care if polynomial regression is the right model for the data, I have to do it.

Comment: `np.polyfit(x, y, 4)` might help. See: https://blog.finxter.com/np-polyfit/

Comment: please create  a [Minimal,Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LarrytheLlama I am not sure if that is what I want. I need to make predictions with a model I create. This function just seems to fit the data to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, some remarks. For full reproducibility, state also your packages and from where you take which functions. Second of all, as already mentioned by @Vinzent in the comment, polynomial of a higher degree will always fit your data better -- that's the basis for Taylor's series. Third of all, let's explore what's going on in your model. You say it's a straight line and it doesn't work. Well, the coefficients say something else:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(1,70)
y = np.array([-1.07312323, -1.12360264, -1.16848888, -1.21237286, -1.24931163,
   -1.24563078, -1.25029589, -1.25804974, -1.26992981, -1.2759396 ,
   -1.31707672, -1.28845207, -1.2553561 , -1.21670196, -1.17405228,
   -1.13823657, -1.10201293, -1.0652651 , -1.01830663, -0.95872599,
   -0.86864519, -0.77287454, -0.67380868, -0.56936508, -0.47234488,
   -0.38025164, -0.28073984, -0.17953134, -0.08026437,  0.01376177,
    0.09177617,  0.15270399,  0.2005737 ,  0.23841612,  0.2860362 ,
    0.34606907,  0.39385415,  0.44154466,  0.49050035,  0.5338063 ,
    0.58003198,  0.61416929,  0.59416923,  0.56887929,  0.53366038,
    0.4907952 ,  0.45338928,  0.40975728,  0.35098762,  0.29307093,
    0.24168722,  0.21576624,  0.25267974,  0.3066606 ,  0.37672389,
    0.45321951,  0.53410345,  0.62491894,  0.72720349,  0.81841313,
    0.9213128 ,  1.03645707,  1.15479503,  1.25998302,  1.35221566,
    1.44653627,  1.52833712,  1.60458778,  1.68225894])

# transforming the data to include another axis
x_new = x[:, np.newaxis].copy()
y_new = y[:, np.newaxis].copy()

for i in range(1,10):
    print(f"Degree {i}")
    polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    x_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_new)

    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x_poly, y_new)
    y_poly_pred = model.predict(x_poly)
    print("Scklearn: ", model.coef_[0], model.intercept_)
    
    coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, i)
    # Generate polynome function f(x)
    f = np.poly1d(coeffs)
    print("Numpy: \n", f)

    plt.scatter(x, y, s=10)
    plt.plot(x_new, y_poly_pred, color='m',label='sklearn')
    plt.plot(x, f(x), color='r', label='np')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

which is gonna give you:

```py
Degree 1
Scklearn:  [0.         0.04205913] [-1.520228]
Numpy: 
  
0.04206 x - 1.52
Degree 2
Scklearn:  [ 0.00000000e+00  4.58554678e-02 -5.42334612e-05] [-1.56515139]
Numpy: 
             2
-5.423e-05 x + 0.04586 x - 1.565
Degree 3
Scklearn:  [ 0.00000000e+00  4.21624962e-02  7.67141331e-05 -1.24711995e-06] [-1.54283792]
Numpy: 
             3             2
-1.247e-06 x + 7.671e-05 x + 0.04216 x - 1.543
Degree 4
Scklearn:  [ 0.00000000e+00 -1.79439905e-01  1.40847170e-02 -3.11025813e-04
  2.21270495e-06] [-0.71710953]
Numpy: 
            4            3           2
2.213e-06 x - 0.000311 x + 0.01408 x - 0.1794 x - 0.7171
Degree 5
Scklearn:  [ 0.00000000e+00 -1.55916194e-01  1.17996085e-02 -2.24932455e-04
  8.34195933e-07  7.87719440e-09] [-0.77753422]
Numpy: 
            5             4             3          2
7.877e-09 x + 8.342e-07 x - 0.0002249 x + 0.0118 x - 0.1559 x - 0.7775
```

I am going here above the degree four you mentioned just to show the case. Notice here a few things. If it was a straight line, you would expect all the coefficients above degree one to be zero, which is not true. However, if you look at eg. degree 3, you get `7.67141331e-05` for `x^2` and `-1.24711995e-06` for `x^3` which is fairly close to zero so you would not expect them to have a big role in your result.

Another proof for you that it's not a linear fit is, if you use the `R^2` of `sklearn` to check how close you are. If you would always have a straight line, then your error should not change. But it it grows, as it should, if you check it (just add `print(model.score(x_poly, y_new))` in the code):

```
Degree 1
0.9078883471490475
Degree 2
0.9083670747869753
Degree 3
0.9084444071378761
Degree 4
0.9817855101145114
Degree 5
0.9820634174954168
```

Do you notice something interesting in the values? Maybe the sudden jump in the model fitness? Or that the first three have very much the same value (although there is some improvement)? Well, isn't it a coincidence that before you weren't happy with the straight line and from degree four you are happy with your model? That's why you want to always see what your model is doing and how it's performing both visually and numerically.

In other words, there is no problem with your code snippet, it just so happened that the coefficients for higher degrees were very close to zero that it looked like a straight line.

---

Note: I included both `sklearn` as in your original post, and `numpy` because others have mentioned it and it has nicer coefficient printing. They're pretty much the same in this case.

HOWEVER, they are not exactly the same in your original case and your question goes much deeper. The reason why `sklearn` fails with your years is much deeper and I recommend reading [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/polynomial-regression-with-scikit-learn-what-you-should-know-bed9d3296f2). Put simply, you need to scale your variables, see below. Also, look up the differences between polynomial regression and interpolation.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import preprocessing

x = np.arange(1950,2019)

y = np.array([-1.07312323, -1.12360264, -1.16848888, -1.21237286, -1.24931163,
   -1.24563078, -1.25029589, -1.25804974, -1.26992981, -1.2759396 ,
   -1.31707672, -1.28845207, -1.2553561 , -1.21670196, -1.17405228,
   -1.13823657, -1.10201293, -1.0652651 , -1.01830663, -0.95872599,
   -0.86864519, -0.77287454, -0.67380868, -0.56936508, -0.47234488,
   -0.38025164, -0.28073984, -0.17953134, -0.08026437,  0.01376177,
    0.09177617,  0.15270399,  0.2005737 ,  0.23841612,  0.2860362 ,
    0.34606907,  0.39385415,  0.44154466,  0.49050035,  0.5338063 ,
    0.58003198,  0.61416929,  0.59416923,  0.56887929,  0.53366038,
    0.4907952 ,  0.45338928,  0.40975728,  0.35098762,  0.29307093,
    0.24168722,  0.21576624,  0.25267974,  0.3066606 ,  0.37672389,
    0.45321951,  0.53410345,  0.62491894,  0.72720349,  0.81841313,
    0.9213128 ,  1.03645707,  1.15479503,  1.25998302,  1.35221566,
    1.44653627,  1.52833712,  1.60458778,  1.68225894])

# transforming the data to include another axis
x_new = x[:, np.newaxis].copy()
y_new = y[:, np.newaxis].copy()

# scaling
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
polyreg_scaled=make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(4),scaler,LinearRegression())
polyreg_scaled.fit(x_new,y_new)

# no scaling
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y_new)
y_poly_pred = model.predict(x_poly)


plt.scatter(x, y, s=10)
plt.plot(x_new, polyreg_scaled.predict(x_new), color='g',label='sklearn scaled')
plt.plot(x_new, y_poly_pred, color='m',label='sklearn')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

will produce:

[image]

As you can see, the scaled version works nice but the unscaled is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

From the sklearn documentation for `PolyFeatures`:

"Generate a new feature matrix consisting of all polynomial combinations of the features with degree **less than or equal** to the specified degree."
So you are not guaranteed to get the degree you specify, it's just the maximum degree.
Without having worked with this function myself, I would guess that it takes the best fit. In your case, it is quite easy to imagine that a polynamial with degree 2 and 3 might be actually a worse approximation of your data than a polynomial of degree 1 (a straight line), due to their specific number of extreme points and inflection points. Therefore, i suspect the code stays with a straight line until you allow degrees up to 4, where 3 extreme points (two inflection points) are possible, which fits your data very well.

The function you are probably better of using is `numpy.polyfit`.

```
import numpy as np
x = df.index.values
y = df['0'].to_numpy()

degree = 4
# Fit coefficients
coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)
# Generate polynome function f(x)
f = np.poly1d(coeffs)


plt.scatter(x, y, s=10)
plt.plot(x, f(x), color='m')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The idea that a polynomial of degree 1 is a better fit than a polynomial of degree 2 or 3, but not better than a polynomial of degree 4 is wrong almost regardless of what your dataset looks like. Keep in mind that the coefficients on the 2'nd and 3'rd order monomials can just be 0.